# dtb not found error

Tags: adb, fastboot, usb-debugging, xiaomi, xiaomi-redmi-note-4g

am trying to boot philz_touch_6.55.0_dior.img in my xiaomi redmi note 4G through the andRoid debug bridge to my phone but when I write the command " fastboot boot philz_touch_6.55.0_dior.img " I get " FAILED  "
what seems to be the problem,please HELP

Comment: Alright, let's piece it all together but first some information from you. Where in your computer is the customrecovery.IMG? Where is the fastboot.exe file? is your device booted into like the OS, recovery, or bootloader? Is your device recognized when the command fastboot device is thrown? What OS version are you running? One version of android 4.xoxo they played around with the fastboot protocol.

Comment: well the customrecovery.img and the fastboot.exe file are in the same folder in the desktop in my computer.My device is booted in bootloader and it is well recognized when the command fastboot device is thrown and am running kitkat android version 4.4.4

Comment: no problem,thanks for the help I did get a new .img and it worked

Answer (score 3):

The custom recovery .IMG is corrupted  and you should go download a different one. In the error you received DTB stands for Device Tree Blob. The device tree blob is a default mechanism to pass low-level hardware information from the bootloader to the kernel.